# Calling HTTP POST request of MERN app from another website

Tags: mongodb, api, http, mern

I have one MERN-stack app, and I want to create a button on another website that can call a specific POST request to modify the DB.

In other words, I want a button in website A to call API from the other app to modify the DB.

Is this possible?

Comment: Yes, this is possible.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.